# What happens to deathmoves after changing class?

Tags: dungeon-world, grim-world

In Grim World, there is presented idea of Death Moves, which allow player character to achieve something remarkable upon death.
How Death Moves should be treated if the player character would change class as a result of "achieving" 11th level or as their own choice? Should it be kept? Should it be changed to match the new class? Any experience considering this particular subject would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Review the rules for Beyond 10th Level. Emphasis mine:

> Changing classes means keeping your ability scores, race, HP, and **whatever moves you and the GM agree are core to who your character is**. You lose all other class moves, replacing them with the starting moves of your new class.

So, if the Death Move from the original class is central to who your character is, then you keep it. If not, you don't.

Since you only die once, it seems reasonable that you and the DM would choose one of the available death moves to keep. If your master plan is to die in an explosion of energy, then maybe you can keep both the Battlemaster and Channeler moves. It's up to you to agree with your DM.